# When clicking a tab on a JTabbedPane the components don't appear immediately

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have an application that includes a `JTabbedPane` and two tabs with some components. My problem is when I click on another tab, it's components do not appear immediately; but when the mouse courser moves over each component (`JCheckBox`, `JButton` and so on) of the tab, the components will appear but not correctly (see below image).

[alt text http://hivaonline.persiangig.com/1.gif](http://hivaonline.persiangig.com/1.gif)

[alt text http://hivaonline.persiangig.com/2.gif](http://hivaonline.persiangig.com/2.gif)

---

[This is my CODE . . .](http://hivaonline.persiangig.com/VehiclesPanel.java)

Comment: It would be helpful if you show some code.

Comment: It would be helpful if your code was readable... 1.) not following Java naming conventions - or *any* naming conventions. 2.) GUI builder auto-generated code mixed in with written code. 3.) lines going over 80 characters (the longest line is *695* characters). 4.) commented out code still lying around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a milion for your response, the problem was calling repaint() of a component that called when i changing it position, the location of marker must be change every time the map move by user or page event occurred, so i think calling repaint() caused a loop and other component not paint correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you mixing some awt and swing stuff?

This could probably make such unpredictable effects.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see an exception on the console? Exceptions in Event Dispatching Thread can cause such behavior.

Comment: No Konrad,there is no exception

Answer (score 1):

As others have observed, your code is incomplete. As a guide, consider this article on the benefits of a [*Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example*](http://sscce.org/). Several such examples are discussed in [*How to Use Tabbed Panes*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html). You might compare them with what you're doing.